# save data before power cut

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm using an Asp.Net core app with angular 2 on the client side.

A counter is displayed in hh:mm:ss format and I'm saving the remaining time in a variable `remaingTime` which is in seconds.

The data is saved to the database by calling an api after every 10 seconds. This works fine, but whenever I refresh or close the browser I am getting an incorrect value from the database. I don't want to have to save the data every second.

Is there any way to save seconds to a database when system crashes or the power goes off?

Comment: What are you saving to the database? If it is an 'elapsed time' from some point in time, you should only need to store that initial reference value and calculate the elapsed time in your client app.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to save data every second, even if you explicitly don't want to save data every second? ("and I dont want to save data after each second"). The answer to that is logically no.

Comment: yes I know that logically it is impractical to save elapse time every seconds..but how can I save elapsed time accurately to the server..?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you are asking. Can you post a simplified code sample or explain in more detail the purpose and intended functionality. I get the impression this might be a case of trying to use the wrong tool to achieve a particular result, but can't tell from the information provided.

Comment: I just want that suppose I have lost my connection from server i.e may be my system shut down unexpectedly or crashes out or in anyway...In that case I want to save the exact time of system crash or it is disconnected from server..How can I achieve that..?